# Parent paddle to left and right hands

Tags: animation, rigging

I am looking to have a character with motion capture animation holding a paddle/stick between both hands. I have tried adding 2 bones to the stick and then using the 'child of' constraint to link bones within the stick to the corresponding left and right hands. I can get it to work with one hand but not both?

I have seen a post in which a paddle controls both hands but not the other way round with the hands controlling the stick ?
Thanks for any help
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up using two modifiers. I used *Copy Transforms,* but *Child Of* will work as well.
[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks Hiserod and sorry for the delay!   That's perfect and should work nicely!

Comment: @NCM Thanks but please read this to keep BSE nice and tidy: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment